# Make only a part of the mesh softbody

Tags: physics, soft-body

I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5JtP8AZKhU&t=5s It doesn't address, and I cannot find any documentation on how to make only a part of the mesh a softbody.

For example, what if I wanted only Suzanne's ears to be floppy? Not the rest of the head? I am using vertex groups to separate the soft/not soft parts of the mesh, but it's not working right.

Comment: to add to Blunder's answer, you can also use Cloth to make part of the body floppy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this is not a partial soft body because the whole mesh is still a soft body. But if you want to make a Suzanne with floppy ears then set the *Goal > Settings > Stiffness* to `0.999`, and define a *Vertex Group* for the head without the ears. Use this group for the *Vertex Group* value of the soft body settings. In the *Object* section increase *Friction* to `6.000`, and decrease *Mass* to `0.2 kg`.

Yay!
[image: Suzanne with floppy ears]