# Adding differing Soft Body params to various Vertex Groups of same character mesh

Tags: soft-body

I have an over-weight character where I would like to apply some "flesh jiggle" to areas like the chin, belly and arms.  One can imagine rather differing parameters to the chin (very loose flesh) versus the belly (more fat).

[image]

However I am only able to add a single Soft Body physics to my character, and I have a pre-defined character mesh (import from DAZ Studio) that would be difficult to separate into "sub-mesh" separate Objects Parented to the same Rig (a solution of having a belly with one Soft Body and a Chin Object with a different Soft Body).   To separate these out would seem like a difficult task, perhaps I'd have a main char that is "whole" with some invisible (?) vertex groups, and duplicate these groups into my sub-objects (ouch!).

Playing around with vertex weight might be another idea, but that requires adjusting each grouping in some magic/imprecise way that seems complex and exhaustively iterative.

How would/have you smart people approach this objective?   I think a solution like this might be similar to a cloth that might have different parts, where one had little control over the source mesh and could only approximate parts based on creating approximate vertex groups.

Comment: I am not sure if Softbody physics works with an armature. You can use the stiffness value to make parts of the mesh soft (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231694/make-only-a-part-of-the-mesh-softbody). Cloth simulation works with an armature for sure. Here you can use the Pin vertex group to control the areas you want to have soft. For different parameters, you could use multiple cloth simulations. Here is a demo with a dinosaur: https://youtu.be/2x3ILWEflSY

Comment: thanks for your time @Blunder.  Yes I got the fleshy double-chin working with a mouth synchronized to a voice.  Rather cool to see the chin "wobble" as he talks.   So now I want to Soft Body his belly as he walks.   My problem is how to VARY the parameters on different vertex groups.  Maybe playing around with vertex weight is one idea, but that requires adjusting each grouping in some magic/imprecise way that seems complex and exhaustively iterative.